# In C fgets and continue are skipping more than one line

Tags: c, arrays, comments, skip

I am trying to skip all lines starting with a "#" my current code seems to be working except when it hits the fourth comment, it then skips the first line of coordinates which I need. The way I have proved this is with two pictures, one with an extra enter added after the comment and the program provides the correct output, and the second with the correct input but incorrect output.(I am required to use the input with no extra line).
I have also attached the section of code where I am encountering the issue. Thanks so much for your help!

[image]

correct output, incorrect added new line to txt file

[image]

code:

```
a = 0 ;                                                                                     
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),fp) != NULL)                                                 
{
    if (line[0] == '#')
    {
    continue;
    }
    else if (MAX_X==0  && MAX_Y==0 )
    {
        if ((sscanf(line,"%d %d", &MAX_X, &MAX_Y)==2) && MAX_X>0 && MAX_X <= 1000 && MAX_Y>0 && MAX_Y<=1000){
            continue;
        }
    }else if (NUM_PT==0)
    {
        if ((sscanf(line, "%d", &NUM_PT)==1)&& NUM_PT>0 && NUM_PT<=1000)
            continue;
    }
    else if((fscanf(fp,"%d %d", &X_COORD[a], &Y_COORD[a]))&& X_COORD[a]>=0 && X_COORD[a]<=MAX_X && Y_COORD[a]>=0 && Y_COORD[a]<= MAX_Y)
    {
       a++;
        continue;

    }
    else if(strcmp(line, "")==0)
    {

       return -1;

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: `fgets()` includes the newline in the input. So `strcmp(line, "") == 0` won't be true for a blank line, since `line` is `"\n"`

Comment: Why are you using `fscanf()` instead of `sscanf()` in the third `else if`?

Comment: ohh well that was the issue! I guess I changed quite a bit of things so I must have somehow missed it. So obvious ahh! Thank you.

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in line

```
else if((fscanf(fp,"%d %d", &X_COORD[a], &Y_COORD[a]))&& X_COORD[a]>=0 && X_COORD[a]<=MAX_X && Y_COORD[a]>=0 && Y_COORD[a]<= MAX_Y)
{
   a++;
    continue;

}
```

You just scanned LINE parameter, and then scan a new line instead of scan parameters from this line.